# Change dialog text Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this piece of code:

```
private void displayMessage(String message)
{


    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirmation, null);
    final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_yes).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your business logic
            deleteDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_no).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    deleteDialog.show();
}
```

What I want to do is to get the message parameter, and put this message in a TextBox from the XML layout of the dialog box. I've tried this:

```
   TextView confirmationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
  confirmationTextView.setText(message);
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
TextView confirmationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
```

With

```
TextView confirmationTextView = (TextView) deleteDialogView .findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
```

Comment: Do vote up as well as you have enough vote to vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

Change by this ->

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirmation, null);
TextView confirmationTextView = (TextView) deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
confirmationTextView.setText(message);
final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
```